# Не получаю ответ с сайта (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Пытаюсь получить ответ сайта, используя библиотеку **Requests** Python 3.9, но ничего не происходит после запуска программы. Ссылка через браузер работает нормально. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.asos.com/ru/nike/belye-krossovki-nike-air-max-2090/prd/21390433'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: значит сайт не желает разговаривать с ботами

Comment: @Эникейщик так и предполагал, спасибо

Comment: ничего не происходит? в status_code что?

Comment: Я попробовал в Google Colab - висит, думает, странно

Comment: @Jack_oS ничего не происходит и в статусе тоже ничего.

Comment: @CrazyElf если вставить ссылку в адресную строку, то все работает. Мб, действительно, стоит защита от ботов?

Comment: А как насчет того, чтоб отправить заголовок?) `requests.get(url, headers=headers)` В переменной headers должен быть словарь с юзер-агентом

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy Ответ пришел, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Интересная защита: без заголовка, вернее с заголовком по-умолчанию, сайт просто не отвечает...
Если передать user-agent в headers:

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

ответ приходит незамедлительно:

```
200
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает